# Name of an old movie that ends with the main characters traveling "North, always North"

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie when I was a kid and have tried to track it down several times, but never was able to figure out the title.

From what I remember, the movie has a male and female main characters and broadly followed a "Journey to the Center of the Earth" plot.  The characters were part of a military operation and at some point find themselves in a hidden land filled with dinosaurs.  I clearly remember a few scenes.

1. A large-scale bombardment of the land when the dinosaurs are discovered.  I think that there is a bit where the top of a triceratops's head plate is blown off by one of the mortars.
2. One of the military people remarks that they need to keep moving further North to find food.
3. The movie ends with the two main characters walking together in a snow storm wearing fur outfits (presumably representing that they are in the Ice Age era).  The male character's voice narrates that they have to keep moving, "North. Always North".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's [The Land That Time Forgot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Land_That_Time_Forgot_(1975_film)) (1975).  The movie has a WWI German U-Boat with the survivors of a sunken British ship which

> happen across an uncharted sub-continent called Caprona, a fantastical
>   land of lush vegetation where dinosaurs still roam, co-existing with
>   primitive man.

I remember the scene with the U-Boat firing on the Styracosaurs (not Triceratops actually). Also from Wikipedia, the movie ends with

> Bowen Tyler and Miss Lisa are stranded, and forced to move northwards.

Comment: Also, it seems I mis-remembered the line about moving "always North". http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkAR0d6FNBQ#t=5365s